# get data from two tables with max date for row

Tags: c#, oracle

I would like to get the list from two table with the condition for the largest date:

table Subject:

```
{id = 1, name = 'Subject 1', status = true},
{id = 2, name = 'Subject 2', status = true},
{id = 3, name = 'Subject 3', status = true},
```

table Days:

```
{id = 1, idSubject = 1, name = 'test1', dateFrom = '2022-10-01', dateTo = '2022-10-10'},
{id = 2, idSubject = 1, name = 'test1', dateFrom = '2022-10-02', dateTo = '2022-12-01'},
{id = 3, idSubject = 1, name = 'test2', dateFrom = '2022-01-01', dateTo = '2022-05-10'},
{id = 4, idSubject = 1, name = 'test90', dateFrom = '2022-01-05', dateTo = '2022-12-06'},
{id = 5, idSubject = 2, name = 'ex1', dateFrom = '2022-10-01', dateTo = '2025-01-05'}...
```

I would like to have data for subject.name = 'Subject 1':

```
{id = 2, idSubject = 1, name = 'test1', dateFrom = '2022-10-02', dateTo = '2022-12-01'},
{id = 4, idSubject = 1, name = 'test90', dateFrom = '2022-01-05', dateTo = '2022-12-06'}
```

I tried like that:

```
select s.id, d.id, d.idSubject, s.name, d.name, d.date_from, d.date_to
from SUBJECT s
join(select max(date_to) date_to, max(date_from) date_from, id, idSubject, name from Days group by id, date_from, date_to) d on s.id = d.idSubject
where s.name = 'Subject 1'
order by d.date_to desc
```

but I get duplicate records

Comment: Please describe (if you were an analyst who writes a specification for developer) how to get what you want as an output.

Comment: this is my test project and unfortunately I have a problem with get the this data – i would like to retrieve data with max date_from and date_to

Comment: A row with maximum`date_from` and  a row with maximum `date_to`? What if two different rows have the same value that is maximum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
with subject AS
(
SELECT 1 as id, 'Subject 1' as name, 'true' as status FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Subject 2', 'true' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Subject 3', 'true' FROM dual
),
days AS
(
SELECT 1 as id, 1 as idsubject, 'test1' as name, TO_DATE('2022-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as datefrom, TO_DATE('2022-10-10','YYYY-MM-DD') as dateto FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'test1' , TO_DATE('2022-10-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2022-12-01','YYYY-MM-DD') FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'test2' , TO_DATE('2022-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2022-05-10','YYYY-MM-DD') FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, 'test90', TO_DATE('2022-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2022-12-06','YYYY-MM-DD') FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2, 'ex1'   , TO_DATE('2022-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2025-01-05','YYYY-MM-DD') FROM dual
)
SELECT ds.*
  FROM days ds
       INNER JOIN subject s ON ds.idsubject = s.id
 WHERE s.id = 1
   AND ds.datefrom IN (SELECT MAX(datefrom)
                         FROM days
                        WHERE idsubject = ds.idsubject)
   AND ROWNUM = 1
 UNION ALL
SELECT ds.*
  FROM days ds
       INNER JOIN subject s ON ds.idsubject = s.id
 WHERE s.id = 1
   AND ds.dateto IN (SELECT MAX(dateto)
                       FROM days
                      WHERE idsubject = ds.idsubject)
   AND ROWNUM = 1;
```